Add a custom menu entry to start external applications in RetroArch
I want to use RetroArch (with XMBC menu bar) on my computer in the living room to primarily play retro games. But it would also be nice to launch other applications like Plex HTPC to use the same computer as a media player.
I installed both RetroArch and Plex HTPC via Snap.
Each one runs independently from the other correctly.
Is there a way to add a custom menu/emulator entry to RetroArch which just calls a bash script?
Example of how I want it to look:

